# Java Backend/Server design setup

Tags: java, architecture

This is a very beginner question.  I have tried to search for advice but am overwhelmed by the amount of information and would like some help with ideas on approaches to server design or what to search for!

What I would like to set up is a backend server that provides search capabilities and business logic and validation across some fairly basic data.  It wont get too large.

I would then like to be able to plug in a website as a front end or a mobile app or a facebook app or even a desktop app..

My question is what is the best way for front ends to hook into the backend? I would like to have various user accounts with permission levels so authorisation would be important.

I generally only code as a hobby so whilst technically I have built a spring based website before the exact semantics of the client server relationship weren't clear to me.  Now I want to separate the backend so that is is agnostic of how the data is displayed or entered completely and can run on a separate machine.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a ton on options.  I had good expirience with  apache CXF rest services (logic encapsulated in java beans, spring configuration)  and pico web remoting ( more exotic, 
but also rest service and plain java objects  providing business logic)

if you ar already using spring, I would recommend to stick with CXF - it integtrates seamlesly ( and is spring configured itself )

Comment: +1 - Web services offer a well supported, well documented, language agnostic interface with good security support (through existing HTTP security mechanisms). This means you'll be able to integrate your back end with pretty much *any* front end (web site, iPhone, Android, desktop, facebook etc).

Comment: Ok then I am going to give it a try that way.  Thank you for your help and feedback.  Rob